# Custom Field in Rmarkdown Header

Tags: html, yaml, r-markdown

I am attempting to make a template for a html rmarkdown document to be used by my team at work. The Word document I'm hoping to replace has a header with a set of fields which are required for our data management process.

The image below shows both the Word document I want to replace and my current best attempt with markdown. The title, author and date fields are nice and simple, they exist in the (YAML?) header. However I am struggling with the job, version and folder path fields. As a current workaround I've used the subtitle for including the folder path. For the final template I'd prefer the extra fields to be in the order of those in the Word document and also for the version, job and path fields to have the same font as the author and date.

From what I've read I believe it may be possible by editing default.html but my HTML knowledge is extremely limited!

The header currently used by my markdown template is,

```
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "S:/path/to/job"
author: Richard Haydock
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%d %B %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
    toc: true
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
    df_print: paged
---
```

[image: Report examples]

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I would also like to know how to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately not